# Javascript printing on mobile devices(ios)

Tags: javascript, printing

I have to add *Print* button to my site. I used tyical `window.print()` solution.

But this method doesn't work in chrome and atomic browser on ios7 but works in safari.

How should I implement this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out: http://www.printfriendly.com/browser_tool

You can integrate their javascript to your web page so that your users can either print directly or print as a pdf. IMHO the window.print() is useless on an iPad or iPhone unless you have a wireless printer nearby. Most of the cases you wont have one nearby. The option above is promising because i can save it to iBooks or Adobe Reader and later print or send it as an email - That's usable.